# Index conditional aggregate query on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, optimization, aggregate

How does one optimize a conditional aggregate query on PostgreSQL?

A example of such query would be:

```sql
SELECT SUM(score) FROM "games" WHERE "PlayerId" = 23 AND "status" = 'FINAL';
```

Indexing `(PlayerId, status)` would help the filter, any tricks or ideas to optimize the aggregation post filtration?

What would be ideal would be no external caching mechanism involved, and a save mechanism to keep a running SUM every time "games" table is updated – similar to how a cache works but a more reliable one.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a special table to contain the sum.

Then create triggers on the original table that add values that are inserted, subtract values that are deleted, do both for an update and set the value to zero on truncate.

You can see a small example of that for the `count` aggregate in [my blog post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-count-made-fast/). Different from that example you will have to have a summation table with one sum per `"PlayerId"` and `status`.

Answer (score 0):

> Indexing (PlayerId, status) would help the filter, any tricks or ideas to optimize the aggregation post filtration?

Yes, make the index on `("PlayerId", status,score)` or maybe `("PlayerId", score) WHERE status='FINAL'` .  Then the scores can be retrieved and summed from the index without visiting the table, in an index-only scan.

For this to work, you may have to VACUUM the table quiet often to keep most pages all-visible.  But if the table in intensively updated to rows located in random places, then it might not even be plausible to VACUUM often enough.

This is simplest and so would be my first choice.  If it is not good enough, then you can use triggers to maintain a summary table in real time, or try to use partitioning to keep related data close together on disk.